# UITextField horizontal alignment in Xcode 5 IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextfield, alignment, xcode5

I am completely new to Xcode, Objective-C and iOS programming (C++ background) so apologies for potentially dumb question.

I have a `UITextField` in which I want centred text. I have tried setting the alignment in IB in the Control section of the Attributes Inspector, but it doesn't work, although vertical alignment works fine.
I have solved the problem by setting the alignment in code as follows:

```
textNumberOfPax.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Is this a bug in IB, or am I being stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely working for me:

[image]

Maybe you were selecting the wrong `UITextField` or something.

Comment: Oops, as I said, I'm new to all this stuff. I can't believe I missed the Alignment setting you've pointed out! I was using the Alignment settings in the Control section at the bottom of your screenshot - what threw me is that playing with the vertical settings moves the text vertically, but the horizontal settings appear to do nothing. Maybe they're not applicable to UITextField. In my own defence, I'm developing on an 11-inch laptop, so it's easy to miss things that are off-screen!